# Application does not see its method

Tags: android

I've extended Application and it looks like belove. The problem is when I want to get the ArrayList from it to the local method it deosn't not recognise method name. What is wrong?

```
public class Application extends android.app.Application{

    private ArrayList<GifModel> globalListOfItemsInList;


    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate();   
        Log.i("<<<<<<<<<<", "IN APPLICATION");
    }

    public void startApplication(final ArrayList<GifModel> list)
    {
        globalListOfItemsInList = new ArrayList<GifModel>(list);
    }

    public void addItemsToTheList(GifModel model)
    {
        globalListOfItemsInList.add(model);
    }

    public ArrayList<GifModel> getGlobalList()   // HERE IS THIS METHOD PROBLEM
    {
        return globalListOfItemsInList;
    }

}
```

And here is where I want to get that list:

```
backUpAllApplicationContent.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Application app = (Application) getApplication();
                ArrayList<GifModel> gifs = app.getGlobalList();  //PROBLEM HERE. THIS METHOD IS UNDEFINED FOR APPLICATION TYPE..........??

            }
        });
```

Comment: I suggest that you change `Application` to something else, like `MyApplication`. I think you are encountering a name clash. The `Application` that the compiler sees is not the `Application` you want.

Comment: Thank you for the fast answer. Yes that was a problem. I've changed the name and it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Dont name your class as Application change class name and try again. or you should specify full class name in your code`(com.ex.Application)`.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes you have to "Clean" project after renaming classes or variables.

In Eclipse: Project -> Clean -> ok